# change GridView table style when sending to outlook

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, outlook-api

I have this code that send GridView data to outlook

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            string str;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            try
            {
                gridView2.OptionsPrint.AutoWidth = false;
                gridView2.OptionsPrint.UsePrintStyles = true;
                gridView2.ExportToHtml(ms);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                str = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally
            {
                ms.Close();
            }

            oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            oMsg.Display(false); 
            oMsg.HTMLBody = OrderNumber + str +oMsg.HTMLBody;
```

the table look like this
[image]

but i want table style to be like this
[image]

how can i do that,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [GridView.AppearancePrint.HeaderPanel.BackColor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.AppearancePrint.property) property to White to change a column header background color.

Refer to the [Appearance and Conditional Formatting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/115548/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Appearance-and-Conditional-Formatting) help article that describes different ways of appearance customizations.

Comment: thanks for your help,The thing that bothers me most is the style of columns,I want it to be as one body not as separate as it shows

Comment: If you change the background color as I mentioned, column headers will be shown in the same manner as regular data cells.

Comment: I tried (white and transparent) but I get the same style

Comment: Column headers of an exported grid become white on my side if the GridView.OptionsPrint.UsePrintStyles option is on and the  GridView.AppearancePrint.HeaderPanel.BackColor property is set to White.